# Goal Conversions are zero

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am trying a simple query using the Query Explorer where the metric is ga:goal5Starts and the dimension is ga:campaign.

In the analytics interface i can see valid values for the Goal 5 Completions for each campaign, but when using the Query Explorer all campaigns have zero goal 5 completions (applys to all my goals. each is reported as zero).

Any ideas as to why the api is different to the interface?

Comment: Include your full query, filters segment dimensions metrics date ranges, samplingLevel. Verify viewId.

Answer (score 0):

Error was in the date range. The goal was not collected at the dare range specified